Congratulations to poncho for earning over 100,000 reputation points!
crypto.se has recently acquired our first 100k rep user!
The user poncho has recently passed the 100k reputation marker. This is the first time this has ever happened on our site and as such is a milestone in the history of our site. 
This is a herculean achievement. For most users, acquiring 100,000 rep on crypto.se appears simply impossible - our site does not receive as much traffic and votes as some others do. 
It required 1,812 answers and 3 questions over the course of 8 years to get here. Additionally, many of those answers are of exceptional quality. 
According to how SE tracks such things, poncho has reached 2.7 Million people with their content on SE.
Let's hear it for poncho! 

Congratulations poncho. I don't think anybody can do what you do for the site. There are others that do a lot behind the scenes, but in the end this site is about getting great answers to great questions. And you supply those - in droves.
I'm always in envy when I see one of yours. Your knowledge and math skills are - and always will be - far, FAR ahead of anything that I will be able to do. That's a humbling thought.
Although 100K is a nice round number, I'm hoping, along with everybody else I presume, that it is just that, a great number. Just like birthdays, we celebrate and then try and add a good year to our lives.
Thank you and I hope to see many other posts from you. I also sincerely hope that I can make sense of a lot of them somewhere in the future :)

"I also sincerely hope that I can make sense of a lot of them somewhere in the future" - the problem in this case may reside more with the writer than the reader

@poncho Definitely not! It's just that my math background is insufficient to fully grasp the answers (the only real big concern of me when I became mod, it can be tricky to fully grasp e.g. close reasons for highly mathematical questions). Your acceptance rate is pretty high :)

Good old @poncho rocked the site with his answers ever since I first stumbled in here. Congrats! Well deserved.


I believe you are be making a Mochrie of me... :-)

Poncho's answers are clear, direct, and accessible to everyone.  Poncho's ability to bring cryptography to the layman is a special skill that is very valuable indeed.
